Google Looker Studio pagination issue in chart when sorted by same values
My dataset example is shown below:



year_month
id
value




2024-04
1
a


2024-04
2
b


2024-04
3
a


2024-04
4
a


2024-04
5
b


2024-04
6
b


2024-04
7
a


2024-03
8
b


2024-03
9
b


2024-03
10
a


2024-03
11
b


2024-03
12
a


2024-04
13
a


2024-04
14
a


2024-04
15
b



They have the same value in year_month, but the id column is unique.
For my needs, I use year_month to sort the table and set the rows per page to 5.
If you want to check all the data, you should click at least two times.
The problem arises when I change the page from 1 to 2; the second page still has some duplicated values, as shown in the pictures below:


IDs 1 and 4 are repeatedly shown on both page 1 and page 2.
I tried some ways to fix the issue, and the most direct method is to change the sorted column. It does work, but for me, it's just a temporary solution because eventually, I have to use year_month to sort.
I am wondering if it's my misunderstanding or if there is another way to fix it. The expected result should display all different values on each page.

How does it behave when primary_sort is set to year_month & secondary_sort is set to id?!
